# How to check out the sum of integers in a <xs:list itemType="xs:integer"/> in XSD 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a couple of attributes defined in this way:

```
    <xs:attribute name="actor" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="percentage" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:list itemType="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
```

What I need to do is creating an assertion that checks out if the sum of the integers in that list (taking care of the blank spaces) is equal to 100 but only in case in my "actor" attribute there is the string "Me". What I thought is something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<xs:assert test="@actor != 'Me' or sum (tokenize(normalize-space((@percentage)),'\s')) = '100'"/>
```

Can you help me finding out where the problem is? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [XSD 1.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1) and [XPath 2.0 Data Model specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel):

> Types derived by list or union are not atomic.

In this case, the important thing that you need to know is that the Schema validator knows that the type of your `percentage` attribute is a list of ints, as it is derived from list (type is not a string). So in this case the data associated with `@percentage` its (for example) the list `(30, 30, 40)` and not the string `"30 30 40"`. This also means you cannot call `normalize-space(@percentage)` as that functions expects a string. Your second error is that you are comparing the result of the sum with the string `"100"` instead of the number `100`.

So the sum comparaison of your assertion should be as simple as this:

```
sum(data(@percentage)) = 100
```

Edit: added data() to expression so it validates also using xerces.

Comment: Ok perfect! What about if I want to check this sum only when in the attribute **actor** there is the string "Me" ? <xs:assert test="@actor != 'Me' or sum(@percentage) = 100"> doesn't work.

Comment: <xs:assert test="@actor != 'Me' or sum(@percentage) = 100"/> should work.

Comment: Mmmm it doesn't unfortunately.. that assertion is applied to this kind of node: <multipleChoice actor="" bar="" points="" numberOfChoices="3" percentage=""> and it gives error if I don't insert in the **percentage** attribute a list of numbers whose sum is 100, even though the **actor** attribute is empty. I would like that the "sum = 100" is required only when in **actor** there is "Me"

Comment: That XML is valid, validate again and check that you don't have any duplicated assertion or that only contains the sum part.

Comment: I have another assertion which is: <xs:assert test="@actor != 'Me' or count(tokenize(normalize-space(string(@percentage)),'\s')) =  @numberOfChoices"/> but this checks out that in the **percentage** attribute there are a certain number of integers which has to be the same number expressed in the **numberOfChoices** attribute. And again this is checked out only if the **actor** attribute is equals to "Me".. so all I want to say is: when **actor**="Me", check out that there are a certain number of integers in that attribute BUT also that their sum is equals to 100

Comment: You can replace both assertions for this one `<xs:assert test="@actor != 'Me' or (sum(@percentage) = 100 and count(data(@percentage)) = @numberOfChoices)"/>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81063/discussion-between-tarta-and-sergiofc).